# INNODB -> Should the default column be zero or null?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, relational-database, innodb

My english is a little weak sorry

When using INNODB, must the column be 0 or should it be null?

Does the problem occur if the joined columns are defined as 0?

Finally, which is better in terms of performance?

Thanks.

Comment: Well `NULL` might potentially have zero storage requirements, while zero would take up space.  It really depends on your data, column definition, etc.

Comment: This is not a PHP question. Do you allow NULL in the column already? If it is an integer I'd use `0`.

Comment: Use `NULL` as meaning "value not set" and you should be pretty right. In SQL NULLs, empty strings, and 0 are all different. Stick to the null definition in the first sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I should still use 0 or null?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the problem.  You do not have to provide a `DEFAULT` value.  You do not have to declare a column `NULL` (or `NOT NULL`).

Instead...

Think about the application.

Case 1:  Your application will *always* have a value for that column, and it will *always* specify the value.  Then declaring the column to be `NOT NULL` and not providing a `DEFAULT` makes sense.

Case 2:  You don't have a value yet.  Example: The table has `start_date` and `end_date`.  You create a row when the thing "starts", so you fill in `start_date` (see Case 1) but leave `end_date` empty.  "Empty" could be encoded as `NULL` and `DEFAULT NULL`.  Later you `UPDATE` the table to fill in the `end_date` with a real value.

Case 3:  The table has a "counter".  When you initially add a row, the counter needs to start with "1".  Later you will `UPDATE ... SET counter=counter+1`.  You could either explicitly put the "1" in when you create the row, or you could leave out the value when inserting, but have the column declared `NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'`

`NULL` could represent "not-yet-filled-in" (Case 1), "don't know the value", "use the default", and several other things.  This is an application choice.

There are other uses for `NULL`.  Unless you have a use for `NULL`, declare each column `NOT NULL`.

If, when `INSERTing`, you specify all the columns, then there is no need for `DEFAULTs`.  `DEFAULTs` are a convenience, not a necessity.  Without a `DEFAULT`, you get "0" for numeric `NOT NULL` columns, or `''` for strings.

Performance -- Probably not an issue.  Do you have a particular example we should discuss?

`JOINing` -- I would avoid joining on a column that might have `NULL` in it.  This rarely happens in "real life", since one joins on the unique identifier for rows in one column with a column in the other table:

```
 FROM A  JOIN B  ON B.id = A.b_id
```

That is, `B.id` is probably the `PRIMARY KEY` of B, hence cannot be `NULL`.  On the other hand, `A.b_id` could be `NULL` to indicate there is no row in `B` corresponding to the row in `A`.  No problem.